# I have a PHP Parsing Error in a line of code that I don't know what is wrong

Tags: php, parsing

I don't know php, but this script is old and supposedly works
I get this error:
 Backend fatal error: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '?' i

from this line

```
if (is_string($arguments[0])) {
            return app('cache')->get($arguments[0], $arguments[1] **??** null);
        }
```

Is something missing or wrong with the ??

Comment: What shall `**??**` be? Before null a comma is missing.

Comment: Those are bold tags for this editor

Comment: so replace ?? with comma?

Comment: Ah, you mean a null coalesce operator. `return app('cache')->get($arguments[0], $arguments[1] ?? null);` working only since php v7.0. Before 7.0 you need to do it manually like `return app('cache')->get($arguments[0], empty($arguments[1]) ? null : $arguments[1]);`

Comment: I just changed php to v7.0 and got this error Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_PARSE)
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE)

Comment: I'm seeing this ?? null, sprinkled throughout the php files

Comment: Are you sure the PHP 7.0 upgrade is finalized? Did you restart the apache service afterwards?